# Springboot: application.properties path motification not taken into account

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-war-plugin

I'm creating a war file from a simple Spring boot (1.x) project, and I would like to modify the Context path.

For that purpose, I have an application.properties file that looks like this:

```
server.contextPath=/newpath
```

The project structure is the following:

```
.
src
    main
    ...
    resources
        application.properties
```

The pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Test project</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>example</finalName>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I perform a **mvn package**, I get a WAR file with the application.properties file located in /WEB-INF/classes, same content as the one I wrote. However, when deploying the war to Tomcat, I cannot access my API thru:

*localhost:8080/newpath/example/some_controller*

I can only query it via:

*localhost:8080/example/some_controller*

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `server.context-path` property only affects an embedded container. When deployed to an external container the context path is determined differently.

In the case of Tomcat, you could copy your application to the `webapps` directory as a file named `newpath.war`. It should then be available at localhost:8080/newpath/example/some_controller.

Comment: The thing about this is the following: I would like to have a newpath context path in order to share the same one as other applications deployed in different war files. This would mean that I will need to have two apps with the same name. Or maybe is there another option to achieve this in the Tomcat side?

Comment: That isn't possible. Each application that's deployed to the same servlet container must have a different context path.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you converted spring boot executable jar project into war file , there are three steps to convert to war file. Please follow steps given in this url - 
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-deploy-war-file-to-tomcat/

Comment: I've already did that in the project; however, I don't think this is the root cause, as I generate and theploy the war file correctly.